# Why each row have to be unique?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I am reading the source code of `spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation`.

Here is the comment from the source code.

> Given a partitioning schematic (a column of integral type, a
>   number of partitions, and upper and lower bounds on the column's
>   value), generate WHERE clauses for each partition so that **each
>   row in the table appears exactly once.**

My question:

1. Why each row has to be unique?
2. Any examples? What's the motivation?
3. What if we have duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment is out of context, you should point to where in the code the comment is, but my guess is that the JDBC connector for spark needs to split the relational table in multiple partitions in order to create an RDD, which is distributed, and so needs to be partitioned. 
To split a table in multiple parts it needs to create multiple slices of data with multiple WHERE clauses,  but each record can go to only one partition in order not to create duplicates.

For instance, if you have a table

```
table tbl
---------
letter | number
a      |1 
b      |2 
a      |3
c      |4
```

you could split using `WHERE number <3` and `WHERE number >=3`
splitting it into 2 parts, but if you use `WHERE number <=3` and `WHERE number >=3` you
end up with one record used in two partitions. So you don't need to have unique rows in the source table, the comment applies to how spark splits the relation, when it does so, it must be sure that each record goes to only one partition.